# 50kb size limit on a webservice transfer?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, web-config

I have a web service and I'm trying to fall its function while sending it data. The data is a byte array, I'm finding that the maximum size byte array I can send is about 50kb (bit less but that's probably due to headers and other things).

How can I increase this size? I was looking at the service web.config and added this to it:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_BasicAuth">
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="64" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
     maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
  </security>
</binding>
```

And also tried:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8000"></httpRuntime>
```

As well but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: WCF is maxing out at 64KB per message - by design, to prevent your web servers from being flooded with huge messages in a Denial-of-service style attack. You can increase that size - there's **TONS** of questions about that already on SO - **search and learn!** (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wcf+max+message+size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also needed to do this, and the following worked:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="6225920"/>
```